# Dual boot issue in HP laptop

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have tried several times, Stack Exchange is my only last hope. Firstly I installed Windows 10 and after that I tried installing Ubuntu, but the install alongside windows option is not available. And then I tried using LVM, even in that while installing Ubuntu, CD/DVD error occurs. I have attached the bios setting photo. Anyone please help me.[bios image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Yhe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are installing Ubuntu 16.04 and have already created free space on hard disk. Instead of going with options install alongside windows or LVM. I will suggest to go with **something else**  option.

Here is the video link you can refer for installation of ubuntu for something else option.
[How To Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_Ja2PRt0cc)